# Running php script from perl program

Tags: php, perl

My perl file and php file are in the same folder. I'm calling php script from perl in cmd

My database.pl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (2) 
{
   my $php = `sample.php`;
   sleep (10);

}
```

My sample.php file

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mydb";   
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "UPDATE users SET name1='Doe' WHERE id=1";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Now when i run `database.pl` file, my `sample.php` file is opening in an editor for every 10 second.. Now how should i make my php file to run, so that it should run UPDATE query.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what operating system you are using, there are different ways. It seems like you are on **Windows** though.

Probably your default action for the `.php` extension is to open it in the editor. Change the backticks line to explicitly run the script with the PHP interpreter.

```
my $php = `php sample.php`;
```

This will of course require that Windows knows where `php` is. It should be in your `PATH` variable.

If you are on **Linux**, you can make the php script executable ...

```
$ chmod u+x sample.php
```

... and call it from the current directoy.

```
my $php = `./sample.php`;
```

---

Note that you can just use [DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI) to do your SQL query from Perl, or implement that loop in PHP and reuse your DB connection there.

Answer (score 0):

Or, to be (kind of) portable, use perl [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

```perl
open(my $proc, 'php sample.php |');
my $php = join('', <$proc>)
```

and, to be sure, that you are executing script in the same directory, use [FindBin](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html) module:

```perl
use FindBin qw($RealBin);
open(my $proc, "php '$RealBin/sample.php' |");
...
```